# Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS Workstation Installer Doesn't Recognize Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7, fedora

I'm a new user evaluating Linux distros. I have a Dual Boot system (Windows 7 and Fedora 21). I would like to install Ubuntu into the partition currently occupied by Fedora (`/dev/sda3`).

The Ubuntu installer sees the Fedora partition and identifies it as such.  The installer sees partition (`/dev/sda2`), but does not recognize it as being occupied by a Windows System.  When I try to install, the options are:

- Install Under Fedora
- Install Ubuntu as the only OS
- Something else

When I go to Something Else and ask to install into `/dev/sda3`, I get the message "No Root File System".  All partitions are primary and the Fedora partition is over 450 GB.

Comment: Do you wanna sub Fedora by Ubuntu? If yes, I'm almost sure that choosing the "Install Under Fedora" option will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your question.
Go to www.ubuntu.com and download the distribution of your choice. Save it to your computer. 
Now, Burn this download to a DVD. 
Put the DVD in to cd/dvd slot and restart your computer.

You have just created a live dvd. I think what is happening is you cannot partition when you are using the operating system. A live dvd will allow you to modify the partition straight from the dvd.

Press CTRL,ALT, and T at the same time. A terminal window will pop up.
Now type this in the terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Follow the prompts, you are almost there. 
Once this is installed, click on the spiral on the very top left corner of the operating system and type "gparted" Your software will pop up.

Finally, follow these instructions found on this website starting on step four and create your partition:http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd.

Answer (score 0):

You should under the partition fedora 21 those change under the setup, and choose ext4 and put it as root the symbol / then you should could install Ubuntu combined whit fedora 21, and after this you have to alther the grub to boot mgrwmv.efi, and the type this in at the bottom.

```
   menuentry "windows 7"
       fi   --uuid     NTFS      --set-root=(uuid of win)

            echo 'booting windows'

            NTFS mgrwmv.efi

            echo 'starting windows'

            NTFS (the uuid of win)
```

and it might work fine this way.