# Grub boot corrupted after installing Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10

I know this question has been asked several times but all the solutions I found googling didn't work at all.

I am not sure if this is a grub issue or windows 10 issue.

So, I had a disk with Ubuntu 14 installed and another one with Windows 7 installed. Windows 7 was a bit laggy since I had a bunch of junk files there so I decided to format and install Windows 10.

As everybody might know, Windows 10 replaced grub, so I went into my Ubuntu Live CD to install grub and updated it. However, when grub finally launched, it indeed shows a Windows partition, but it says "Windows 7". When I boot it, I get a Windows Bootloader error (0xc000000f) and I have to reboot.

My ubuntu partition boots fine but I get an error when I try to open my Windows partition :/

As an alternative solution, I downloaded boot-repair but it didn't work at all. The logs show some errors.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12199033/

Thanks.

Comment: With Windows 8 or later you must turn off the fast startup or always on hibernation. Grub will not boot hibernated Windows. Since your Windows is a separate drive, reinstall the Windows boot loader to that drive, and boot that drive to turn off the fast startup. Then change BIOS to boot Ubuntu drive. With multiple drives, do not use Boot-Repair's auto fix as it just puts grub into the MBR of every drive.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try this see link:

[Booting into windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654483/how-do-i-make-my-computer-automatically-boot-into-windows-instead-of-ubuntu/654562#654562)

[Booting problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613943/ubuntu-14-04-02-lts-workstation-installer-doesnt-recognize-windows-7/642110#642110)

[Reinstalling grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572558/cant-boot-after-deleting-efi-boot-and-windows-partition/572577#572577)

and it might work fine this three ways.